# How to delete index in Neo4j1.9.9?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

Question1:
Is there any way to delete a node indexes except using Neo4j REST API?

Question2:
Neo4jTemplate.delete(T entity) will delete the node. Does it delete all the node indexes as well?

Question3:
use the following Cypherto delete node and its relationships. Does it delete the node indexes as well?
 start node=node({nodeId}) match node-[r]-() delete r, node

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean delete the node from the index or the entire index? Either way,

1. Yes, you can remove a node from the indexusing the Java API if you have access to the embedded api (http://neo4j.com/docs/1.9.9/indexing-remove.html). Deleting the entire index is also possible using [theIndex.delete()](http://neo4j.com/docs/1.9.9/indexing-delete.html)
2. SDN (<4.x) will remove the node from the index. It will not delete the entire index.
3. No, you must manually remove the node from the index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1. yes you are right. I can use spring neo4j data API to delete index.
2. do you mean I need to write some code to delete the node index in version 1.9.9?

Comment: What I want is that delete all indexes belongs to the node when deleting the node.

Comment: The indexes in 1.9.9 have to be manually managed. So you'll need to write some code (maybe a server extension if you use the Neo4j server) to delete the indexes when the node is deleted.